# Apostrophes issu with php and jscript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this piece of code, which doesn't work, I couldn't find where is the problem?

```
$texttt = "blabla";
    echo "<div onclick='select(\" page d \' accueil \");'>".$texttt."</div><br/>";
function select(text){
      alert(text);          
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

" is breaking your php statement

```
echo "<div onclick=\"select(' page d\' accueil ');\">\"Page d'accueil\"</div><br/>";



function select(text){
      alert(text);          
}
```

try to use `addslashes` and `htmlentities` to escape the quotes between text

```
$texttt = htmlentities(addslashes($text), ENT_QUOTES); 

echo "<div onclick='select(\"$texttt\");'>$texttt</div><br/>";
```

Comment: When I put a simple string without apostrophes everything works normally.
I have changed the text inside the div so that I could decrease the problems.

Comment: try to escape the string inside php statement

Comment: I've tried all possibilities, nothing works till now!!

I don't know what do u mean "try to escape the string inside php statement"?

I have to send string which contains lots of apostrophes within my function's param

Comment: I don't neither understand why it it works when I send a string without apostrophes?
So the problem's with the apostrophes, having said that, why it doesn't work when I put the anti-slash?

Comment: try to use htmlentities(addslashes($text), ENT_QUOTES);

Comment: Thanks Harish, it works now with the apostrophes, but it still has problem with the French special characters such as : éèçà ect
it shows nothing when it comes to those!!

Comment: Ok it works now, I'd just to add : htmlentities(addslashes($text), ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-15')

Thanks again Harish :)

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes for PHP. I use single quotes for PHP (which is server side script) and double quotes for client side scripts unless it is not obligatory.

```
echo '<div onclick="select(\'page d\'accueil\');">"Page d\'accueil"</div><br/>';
```

the problem is sourced by single quote in `d'accueil`:

I dont know if it is possible to escape a string which is located in another escaped string.

The possibilities:

- You can change the grammar rules of your language:

  - Affects too many people.
  - Not applicable.
- You can change the way of typing single quote: using `&#39;` in context.

I have typed a new code (which is working well) for you :

```
<?php
    echo '<div onclick="select(this.innerHTML);">"Page d&#39;accueil"</div><br/>';
?>
<script>
function select(text){
      alert(text);          
}
</script>
```

Comment: It works with double quotes as well, he just needn't escape them.

Answer (score 0):

you should avoid useless quotes before you get lost inside.

`"Page d'accueil"` don't need to be between quotes so remove them.

Use one kind (single or double quotes) for the first level of quoting, and the other for the next levels, and keep that it mind.

```
<? php echo '<div onclick="select(\" page d\' accueil \");">Page d\'accueil</div><br/>'; ?>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function select(text){
        alert(text);          
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use heredoc syntax
refreence : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

```
    echo <<<EOT
My name is "$name". I am printing some $foo->foo.
Now, I am printing some {$foo->bar[1]}.
This should print a capital 'A': \x41
EOT;
```

**also try this:**

```
echo json_encode("<div onclick='select(" page d ' accueil ");'>{$texttt}</div><br/>");
```